# Execute CMD.EXE with CreateProcessWithLogonW() without a new console

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have to run `cmd.exe` with `CreateProcessWithLogonW()` but in the context of my program without creating another console, but MSDN says the `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` flag has been set by default. How can I unset this flag so this API doesn't create a new window for my child process?

The following code shows how this API is used in my program. I don't want the new program to run in a new console, but I could not find a solution for that.

```
BOOL status = FALSE;
DWORD process_flags = 0 | arg_process_flags;
DWORD logon_flags = 0 | arg_logon_flags;
PTSTR duplicate_command_Line;
PPROCESS_INFORMATION ptr_process_info;
STARTUPINFO startup_info;
RtlZeroMemory(&startup_info, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
startup_info.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);

if (ptr_process_info = arg_process_infos ? arg_process_infos : (PPROCESS_INFORMATION)LocalAlloc(LPTR, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION)))
{
    if (duplicate_command_Line = _wcsdup(arg_command_Line))
    {
        switch (arg_type)
        {
            case KULL_M_PROCESS_CREATE_NORMAL:
                status = CreateProcess(NULL, duplicate_command_Line, NULL, NULL, FALSE, process_flags, NULL, NULL, &startup_info, ptr_process_info);
                break;

            case KULL_M_PROCESS_CREATE_USER:
                status = CreateProcessAsUser(arg_user_token, NULL, duplicate_command_Line, NULL, NULL, FALSE, process_flags, NULL, NULL, &startup_info, ptr_process_info);
                break;

            case KULL_M_PROCESS_CREATE_LOGON:
                status = CreateProcessWithLogonW(arg_user, arg_domain, arg_password, logon_flags, NULL, duplicate_command_Line, process_flags, NULL, NULL, &startup_info, ptr_process_info);
                break;
        }

        if (status && (arg_auto_close_handle || !arg_process_infos))
        {
            CloseHandle(ptr_process_info->hThread);
            CloseHandle(ptr_process_info->hProcess);
        }

        if (!arg_process_infos)
            LocalFree(ptr_process_info);

        free(duplicate_command_Line);
    }
}
```

Comment: On a side note, you can calling `LocalFree(ptr_process_info)` in the wrong place.  You leak `ptr_process_info` if `arg_process_infos` is null and `_wcsdup()` returns null. `LocalFree()` needs to be called inside the `if (ptr_process_info ...)` block, not inside the `if (duplicate_command_Line ...)` block.

Comment: when you start process via `CreateProcessWithLogonW` it will be run in another logon session, even if you use the same user name as current running. from another side system exec/use *conhost.exe* from the same logon session as console application. as result new process can not use your console (*conhost.exe*). so and even if you do not set `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`, the system functions as if it were set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [redirected input and output of child process](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Here's my test program(remove the error checking).

Parent:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#define BUFSIZE 4096 
void main()
{
    printf("in Parent \n");
    HANDLE R_In, R_Out, R_err, W_In, W_Out, W_err;
    HANDLE hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    HANDLE hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;
    BOOL bSuccess;
    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    CreatePipe(&R_In, &W_In, &saAttr, 0);
    CreatePipe(&R_Out, &W_Out, &saAttr, 0);
    CreatePipe(&R_err, &W_err, &saAttr, 0);
    PROCESS_INFORMATION process_info;
    STARTUPINFO startup_info;
    RtlZeroMemory(&startup_info, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    startup_info.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    startup_info.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    startup_info.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
    startup_info.hStdInput = R_In;
    startup_info.hStdOutput = W_Out;
    startup_info.hStdError = W_err;

    BOOL ret = CreateProcessWithLogonW(L"username",L"domain",L"password", 0,L"ChildProcess.exe",NULL, CREATE_NO_WINDOW,NULL,NULL,&startup_info,&process_info);
    CloseHandle(R_In);
    CloseHandle(W_Out);
    CloseHandle(W_err);
    CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
    DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
    bSuccess = ReadFile(hStdin, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
    bSuccess = WriteFile(W_In, chBuf, dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
    while (1)
    {
        bSuccess = ReadFile(R_Out, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
        if (bSuccess == 0 & GetLastError() == ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE) // child process exit.
            break;
        bSuccess = WriteFile(hStdout, chBuf, dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
    }
    WaitForSingleObject(process_info.hProcess, INFINITE);
    printf("Parent exit\n");
}
```

Child:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#define BUFSIZE 4096 
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
void main()
{
    CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
    scanf("%s", chBuf);
    printf("in Child %s\n", chBuf);
    printf("Child exit\n");
    return;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: So what happens when the console program prompts for a password or asks for character-by-character input?

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean you don't want to create a new window?
try `startup_info.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;startup_info.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;` then it won't create a window.

Comment: I wanted the new process to get to execute in the parent environment not creating another console.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't comprehend properly.

Comment: @KLightning - if you use *CreateProcess**WithLogon**W* - child process will be execute in **new logon session**. it can not execute in parent environment

Answer (score -1):

It's been awhile, but passing `DETACHED_PROCESS` should work.

If not, you can call `CreateProcessWithLogonW` passing it a win32 binary that you provide (possibly your own with different options) that in turn will call `CreateProcess` opening `cmd.exe` without passing `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`.

Unless you're already admin, creating in the same console is utterly impossible, and if you are admin, it's an arcane technique you're better off not using.

Comment: "passing DETACHED_PROCESS should work" - no. [*This value cannot be used with CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags) - we got error invaid parametr in ths case. with second variant we can run process without console at all. but not use the same console as parent

Comment: @RbMm: It's not redily apparent that OP wants same console as parent from the question, but if he does he needs to rethink what he's trying to do.